# Is there a way to pass domain credentials from the originating browser in webHttpBinding wcf service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dns, wcf-security, wcf-client

Is there a way to pass domain credentials from the originating browser in webHttpBinding WCF service?
I'm thinking this should be possible as when I log into any aspx page with Windows Authentication enabled in IIS, I can get the calling user's domain credentials. How would I setup my WCF service in such a manner? Currently the user identity I get in the WCF service are those of the app pool the svc is running under?

***EDIT***

I don't have .NET 4 -- My configuration file is below, but I still get an error:

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication
>   but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

Should I explicitly enable Anonymous for that path in IIS? I think this would undo my efforts to get the domain name.

```
<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Awesome.Project.OperationsBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
</serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Awesome.Project.OperationsServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Awesome.Project.OperationsServiceBehavior"
        name="Awesome.Project.Operations">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
         contract="Awesome.Project.Operations" 
         behaviorConfiguration="Awesome.Project.OperationsBehavior" 
         bindingName="windowsSecurityWebHttpBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
             contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
      </service>
</services>

<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="windowsSecurityWebHttpBinding">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Who is calling the service - the browser or the aspx page?

Comment: IT would originate from the browser.

Comment: change bindingName to bindingConfiguration in your endpoint

Comment: Updated my answer to also show 3.5 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on authentication in the service - assuming .NET 4 add the following to your config

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

for .NET 3.5 or 3.0 you need

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBindingConfig">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service ...>
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration = "webBindingConfig" binding="webHttpBinding" .../>
  </service>
</services>
```

**Edit for additional questions:**

WCF will generally not pass credentials over non secured transports - that's why mode="Transport" is important. If you got rid of it its the same as Mode="None" for WebHttpBinding

If the site is considered to be in the intranet zone then IE will pass the user's credentials automatically. However, non-IE browsers will not and so will hit the site anonymously before getting a 401 and then sending the credentials. The intial request requires anonymous access to be supported in IIS as WCF handles the authentication mechanism

If you need to get hold of HttpContext you can use [Asp.NET Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx). However in WCF you can use ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name to get the authenticated user

Comment: Wouldn't he also have to set the impersonation behavior attribute on either specific operations or the service as a whole?

Comment: if he wants to see the client identity in the service and the browser is calling the service then thats all he needs to do - if he wants to *use* the clients identity or the aspx code is calling the service then yes you are right

Comment: Ah..ok.  Didn't catch that nuance at first.  Thanks :)

Comment: Updated description with my efforts; still hiccups -- Maybe this isn't supported pre .NET 4?

Comment: Thanks! I implemeted your changes. I had to get rid of mode='transport' so that it would work over plain old http instead of https. Unfortunately, I still can't get the current user using HTTPContext..

Comment: Additionally, when I do get prompted for credentials in a non-IE browser, I get 'Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.'

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Impersonate the Original Caller in WCF Calling from a Web Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650591.aspx) gives a walkthrough on how to do this.